# Change a Microsoft Office 2007 installation remotely

Tags: installation, microsoft-office, remote, remote-control

Windows XP:  I have several computers with a Microsoft Office 2007suite installed where we chose not to install the Outlook module. A new project now requires Outlook to be installed on them.

Is there a way to initiate the change remotely? Obviously we could do it individually by:

> Add/Remove programs > Microsoft Office 2007 > Change > then include the Outlook component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on installing Office 2007 [here](http://www.appdeploy.com/packages/detail.asp?id=860), once you get the MSP then start `msiexec` to install Office with all the components you want. You can use `psexec` to start the process remotely.

The installation should layer over the top of your current Office 2007 deployment.

Answer (score 0):

what about plain, old, remote control?  Or: write and deploy a script to carry out those steps you mentioned above?